# $f \in L^+$ with $\int f = k < \infty$ then $\{x : f(x) = \infty\}$ has measure zero proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I have come up with a proof that if $f \in L^+$ with $\int f = k < \infty$ then $\{x : f(x) = \infty\}$ has measure zero. However, all of the proofs I have seen use contradiction but I did not. So I would appreciate if someone could verify/critique my attempt. As usual, $L^+$ is the set of measurable functions from some space $X$ to $[0, \infty]$.

Define the sets $E = \{x : f(x) = \infty \}$ and $E_n = \{x : f(x) > n \}$ for $n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$. It then follows that:
$$E = \bigcap_{n \geq 0}E_n$$
Moreover, we have the following set inclusions:
$$E_0 \supset E_1 \supset E_2 \supset \space ...$$
And $\mu(E_1) < \infty$ because:
$$\mu(E_1) \leq \int_{E_1}f \leq \int_Xf = k < \infty$$
Thus, one can invoke "continuity from above" to assert that:
$$\mu(E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_n) \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$$
Then, by properties of integrals, we have the following estimates for $n \geq 1$:
$$0 \leq n\mu(E_n) \leq \int_{E_n}f \leq \int_Xf = k < \infty$$
Dividing the above inequalities by $n$ yields:
$$0 \leq \mu(E_n) \leq \frac{k}{n}$$
So by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_n) = 0$. Thus, $\mu(E) = 0$ by $(1)$ which completes the proof.

It seems correct, however I am unsure if it is true that the set $E$ can be written as the intersection of the $E_n$'s. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes it is in the axioms of (non-negative) measures/sigma-algebras/integrals wrt a measure that for $E_n\supset E_{n+1}$ measurables if $\mu(E_1)< \infty$ then $\mu(\lim E_n) = \lim \mu(E_n)$, looking at $B_n = E_1-E_n\subset B_{n+1}$ this is the same as the countably infinite union axiom. The other axiom is the obvious behavior under finite union and intersection.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the comment. However, I was not worried about my use of that theorem. I am mainly concerned about my proof as a whole and writing the set where $f$ is infinite as the intersection of the $E_n$